# Is there a jQuery selector for header (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, or h6)?

Tags: jquery

There doesn't seem to be a way in jQuery to tell if a node is a header, i.e., h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, or h6.  I'd like to write something like:

```
hNode$ = $(node).closest('h');
if(hNode$.length >0){
      hNode$.css('padding-top', '+=' + 1);
}
```

where I bump the top padding if the selected line is a header.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes there is.

You can select all headers using `jQuery(":header")`

Here is a link to the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/

> Note that because this selector is a jQuery extension and not part of
>   the CSS specification, queries using this selector cannot take
>   advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM
>   `querySelectorAll()` method. To achieve the best performance when
>   using these selectors, first select some elements using a pure CSS
>   selector, then use `.filter()`.

Comment: Should be noted, like it says in the link, that it's not a css standard selector and thus is probably going to be slower than the collective search for all the headers (or, at the very least, not faster).

Comment: Yes thank you. l have updated and included that in my answer.

Comment: jQuery uses this regex `/^h\d$/i` to filter elements.