# Generate Table of content dynamicaly with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I generate table of contents dynamically. following is my code but its only for one heading tag h3. I need it to work for all headings.
Here is my following sample format of the post :

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>


<div id="tableofcontent"></div>
<div class="entry-content">
<h1 id="Test1">Main Heading</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<h2 id="Test2"> Sub Heading</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
  <h3 id ="Test3">Sub Sub Heading</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
    <h4>Sub Sub Heading</h4>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
   </div>
   </body> 
</html>
```

How do I generate table of contents dynamically.
following is my code but its only for one heading tag h3. I need it to work for all headings.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $aWithId = $('.entry-content h3[id]');
  if ($aWithId.length != 0) {
    if ($aWithId.length > 0) {
      $('#tableofcontent').prepend('<nav class="toc"><h3 class="widget-title">Table of Contents</h3><ol></ol></nav>');
    }

  }
   

var $aWithId = $('.entry-content h3[id]');
if ($aWithId.length != 0) {

  $('.entry-content').find($aWithId).each(function() {
    var $item = $(this);
    var $id = $(this).attr('id');
    var li = $('<li/>');
    var a = $('<a/>', {
      text: $item.text(),
      href: '#' + $id,
      title: $item.text()
    });
    a.appendTo(li);
    $('#tableofcontent .toc ol').append(li);
  });
}
});
```

Comment: Please include the corresponding HTML, CSS code.

Comment: Please make sure you also have a [mcve] - which includes javascript which is valid. (ie `$for` is not valid javascript)

Comment: Hi this is for blog on wordpress site I just needed to add table of content to my blog.

Comment: @ApoorvaSingh You still need to include the relevant html, without it we can't give you a clear answer about where the problem in your code is.

Comment: Try putting *all* your code inside doc.ready, not just the prepend part.   If it's a blog, the blog entries are *possibly* loaded dynamically, so you might also need to wait for that / hook into an event other than doc.ready.  *EDIT* loaded your code into an IDE and it shows an extra `}` - so maybe it is supposed to be all in doc.ready already.

Comment: Your [code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/eyjur6pd/) with related HTML (mostly copied from the deleted answer, credit due).  So there must be some other issue, such as running it too soon (before the `h3` tags exist).     Check with `console.log($aWithId.length)` to see how many it finds *at the time your code runs*.

Comment: *but its only for one heading tag h3* - but your sample only includes one `h3`...  (and doesn't include `class=entry-content`).  Other than that... [still works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/eyjur6pd/1/)

Comment: @freedomn
My problem is it only work for h3 i want them to work for all headings and also check that this heading have any ids or not

Comment: @ApoorvaSingh wow, well that wasn't very clear... thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Sorry @freedomn I am new at development and stackoverflow

Comment: No worries.  It's a fine line between not enough info and adding too much info.  My bad for not recognising your term "headers" to mean h1/h2 etc.

Comment: Change your `var $aWithId` to: `var $aWithId = $('.entry-content').find(":header").filter("[id]");`  you have it twice, but just remove the second one.

Comment: This probably answers your question (but I didn't want it to auto-close as I no longer get to "vote"):  [Is there a jQuery selector for header (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, or h6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369872/is-there-a-jquery-selector-for-header-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-or-h6/28369918)

Comment: Thanks a lot let me check that on my end

Comment: Thanks a lot it working fine but just a little doubt. If I want to show them in successive order H1 H2 H3... and so on..

Comment: You'll have to loop them, eg `$aWithId.filter("h1").each...` you could either use an array `["h1","h2"].each(h => $aWithId.filter(h)...` or generate them `for (var h=1;h<7;++h) { $aWithId.filter("h" + h)...`